# Upload File to Django Admin, Process it, and Deliver to Template

Tags: python, django, jupyter, nbconvert

I would like to upload a file object in the admin, run a process on this to convert it to html, and deliver the result to a template.  I cannot figure out how to access the file object in order to run the handler, but the file itself is `.json` (jupyter notebook). Here is a basic model:

```py
#blog/models.py
class FileUploader(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    notebook = models.FileField(upload_to='./notebooks/')
```

In my views I have a notebook converter function:

```py
#blog/views.py
def upload_file(request):
    notebook_html =  converter(request.FILES['notebook'])
    return render(request, 'test.html', context={'html': notebook_html})
```

then, in my urls I have:

```py
#blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.upload_file, name = 'notebook_page')
]
```

When I go to view the page, I get a `MultiValueDictKeyError at /blog/
'notebook'` error.  I'm not sure how to access the notebook file itself to run the conversion process on, not sure where in the `MultiValueDict` object this is or how it works. Big idea is to upload the file, convert it to html, inject in template.

Comment: Hey! Have you figured this out, a year later? Would be helpful :)

Comment: Nope haha. There are some alternatives like jupyterbook that I’ve been using instead